# Creating a grouped barplot with only a single fill per category

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a grouped barplot with facet but i'm out of ideas on how to not make a grouped one on year with just `fill=year` since I want the fill to be based on the category but the group still exhibits frequency pear year. Another issue is on factors in facet and `space = "free"` is not working as i expect it to be.

```r
Category = c("Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse", "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse")
Year = c("2019", "2019", "2019", "2018", "2018", "2018", "2017", "2017", "2017")
Severity = c("Hunter", "Hunter", "Prey", "Hunter", "Hunter", "Prey", "Hunter", "Hunter", "Prey")
Frequency = rpois(9, 30)
EXP = data.frame(Category, Year, Frequency, Severity)

ggplot(data=EXP, aes(x=Category, y=Frequency, fill=Year))+ theme_whitenb() + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge())  + theme(legend.title = element_blank()) + labs(y = "", x="") + facet_grid(rows = vars(Severity), space = "free")  +
  scale_fill_hue(c=75, l=70) + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
                                     panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_rect(
      fill="#0B0B7A"), strip.text.y = element_text(
        color = "white", face = "bold"
      )
  ) + coord_flip()
```

Expected:
*Mouse not in hunter even if 0 frequency
*Cat and Dog not in prey even if 0 frequency
*Dog, Cat, Mouse have their each color but not per year.

EDIT: MR. Yifu has the answers I Need! thanks btw. I just need to find a way to remove factors in the panels that has 0 frequency.

Comment: Can you show us your desired output? What I understand is that you want to group by Year but fill by Category. I think `aes(x=Category, y=Frequency, fill=Category ,group = Year)` could be what you need.

Comment: Yes this is it!!! thanks. Just need to get rid of factors in the facet that has 0 frequency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm dropping this question, I've yet to find a solution to the faceting even when `space = "free"` is included or other alternative forms.

Answer for fill is just simply fixing up my aesthetic with `aes(x=Category, y=Frequency, fill=Category ,group = Year)` Thanks Yifu Yan!

Answer (score 0):

Does this capture what you want? If not, could you describe which aesthetics (i.e. x, y, fill, facet) you want mapped to which variables?

[image]

Comment: I did that at first but I wanted to show the trend in frequency of Dog, Cat, and Mouse hence it it needs to be grouped.

Comment: The plot i did is already correct, it's just that the colors bother me. I want the color to be the categories (cat, dog, mouse) but the plot should but the group should be the same still.